# Queryset filter: retrieve manytomany field as list of each object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to retrieve every object of a model with only their id and a list of ids they have in a many to many field.

My models :

```
class Wordlist(models.Model):
  words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)


class Word(models.Model):
  word = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

I have this code :

```
list(Wordlist.objects.all().annotate(w=F('words')).values_list('pk', 'w'))
```

And it gives me this :

```
[{'pk': 1, 'w': 7},
 {'pk': 1, 'w': 13},
 {'pk': 1, 'w': 17},
 {'pk': 2, 'w': 29},
 {'pk': 1, 'w': 42},
 {'pk': 3, 'w': 52},
 {'pk': 2, 'w': 65}
 ...
]
```

What i want is :

```
[{'pk': 1, 'w': [7, 13, 17, 42,...]},
 {'pk': 2, 'w': [29, 65,...]},
 {'pk': 3, 'w': [52,...]},
 ...
]
```

A simple solution would be to combine the dicts based on their ids but I don't think it's a good practice and very efficient, since we could have dozens of thousands dicts as a result.

Also, I wondered if it was possible to do the opposite with a single request; retrieving a list of `Wordlist` a word is in for each word in a request on `Word`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use PostgreSQL you can use array_agg function that implemented in `django.contrib.postgres` package. Your query will look like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import ArrayAgg

Wordlist.objects.annotate(arr=ArrayAgg('words')).values_list('id', 'arr')
```

Comment: I use PostgresSQL indeed, I never came across this before, it's really useful, thanks.

Comment: This is nice solution

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result using MySQL and Django 3.x?

Comment: @user1045680
Did you find solution? I faced same problem.

Comment: In my case, Wordlist.word.throught.objects.filter(some condition).values_list(what you want)

This logic is enough for me.